# Dataframe group by including first value of another group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is my simplified example dataframe:

```
  timestamp   A  B  C

1422404668   1   1  2
1422404670   2   2  3
1422404672  -3   3  4
1422404674  -4   4  5
1422404676   5   5  6
1422404678  -6   6  7
1422404680  -7   7  8
1422404680   8   8  9
```

Is there a way to group by positive and negative values and get first value of each group in column A, mean values of column B (including the first value of next group) and difference between first value of next group and first value of current group for column C as below output

Expected output:

```
timestamp    A  B     C
1422404668   1  2     2
1422404672  -3  4     2
1422404676   5  5.5   1
1422404678  -6  7     2
1422404680   8  8     9
```

Data:

```
{'timestamp': [1422404668, 1422404670, 1422404672, 1422404674,
  1422404676, 1422404678, 1422404680, 1422404680],
 'A': [1, 2, -3, -4, 5, -6, -7, 8], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

I'm using the below code to get group by and mean values and difference in the group but how to include the first value of next group in mean difference (column B and C)

```
m=df['A'].lt(0)
df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).agg(
            {'timestamp': 'first',
             A: 'first',
             B: 'mean',
             C: lambda x: x.iat[-1]-x.iat[0] if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]
             }).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: You want to group by *consecutive* positive and negative values in column A?

Answer (score 0):

For aggregate `mean` also include next first value aggregate `sum`, `size` and `first` and count `mean` affter aggragation with shifted values `first` and similar way get difference first values of `C`:

```
m=df['A'].lt(0)
df = df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).agg(
            {'timestamp': 'first',
             'A': 'first',
             'B':['sum','size','first'],
             'C':'first'})
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

df['B'] = (df['B_sum'].add(df['B_first'].shift(-1))
                      .div(df['B_size'].add(1))
                      .fillna(df['B_first']))
df['C'] = (df['C_first'].shift(-1)
                        .sub(df['C_first'])
                        .fillna(df['C_first']))
print (df)
   timestamp_first  A_first  B_sum  B_size  B_first  C_first    B    C
A                                                                     
1       1422404668        1      3       2        1        2  2.0  2.0
2       1422404672       -3      7       2        3        4  4.0  2.0
3       1422404676        5      5       1        5        6  5.5  1.0
4       1422404678       -6     13       2        6        7  7.0  2.0
5       1422404680        8      8       1        8        9  8.0  9.0
```

---

```
df = (df[['timestamp_first','A_first','B', 'C']]
              .rename(columns={'timestamp_first':'timestamp','A_first':'A'}))
print (df)
    timestamp  A    B    C
A                         
1  1422404668  1  2.0  2.0
2  1422404672 -3  4.0  2.0
3  1422404676  5  5.5  1.0
4  1422404678 -6  7.0  2.0
5  1422404680  8  8.0  9.0
```